# Java: If statement not producing result that I am expecting for simple user authentication

Tags: java, if-statement, authentication

When running below program I'm thinking that it should print out "Authentication successful" if I input
"john smith" as user name and "12345" as userID, but instead it just comes back with "Authentication failed". I am calling this method in the Main class. Any suggestions?

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Account {

    public String userNameInput;
    public String userIDInput;
    public String userName = "john smith";
    public String userID = "12345";
    
    public void userDetails(){
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter user name:");
        userNameInput = userInput.next().toLowerCase();

        System.out.println("Please enter user ID:");
        userIDInput = userInput.next();

        if(userNameInput.equals(userName) && userIDInput.equals(userID)){
            System.out.println("Authentication successful");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Authentication failed!!");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try to debug it by yourself to see what your program is doing. Start by printing your variables `userNameInput` and `userIDInput` after reading them (or if you know how to use a debugger, debug it that way). Do they contain the expected content?

Comment: `userInput.next()` will only read one token at a time. So, the first one will read `john`, the second will read `smith`.

Comment: Thanks, changing userInput.next() to userInput.nextLine() worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `next()` to `nextLine()` in `userNameInput = userInput.nextLine().toLowerCase();`

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Account {

    public String userNameInput;
    public String userIDInput;
    public String userName = "john smith";
    public String userID = "12345";
    
    public void userDetails(){
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter user name:");
        userNameInput = userInput.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        System.out.println("Please enter user ID:");
        userIDInput = userInput.next();

        if(userNameInput.equals(userName) && userIDInput.equals(userID)){
            System.out.println("Authentication successful");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Authentication failed!!");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Always use sysout() or try debugging . That will help you a lot.